# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency in AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

hi I'm trying to do a custom AuthenticationProvider but i'm, having torubles with the autowire annotation. i have a class that find users in my database and then authenticate them with a LDAP server, i have the logic but i cant manage to pass this autowire error.

this is the class that implements WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
package com.abc.config;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.auth"}) 
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {




    @Autowired 
    private AuthProvider authent; <--- this is the autowire that gives me troubles

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception 
    {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(authent)
            .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
            .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/prueba")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
            .logout()                                    
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

this is my JPA configuration class

```
package com.abc.config;
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.abc.dom", "com.abc.repo", "com.abc.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.abc.repo")
public class ConfigJPA 
{

       @Bean
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
               throws ClassNotFoundException 
       {

          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em  = 
                  new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

          em.setDataSource( dataSource() );
          em.setPackagesToScan("com.abc.dom");
          em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
          em.setJpaProperties( asignProperties() );

          return em;
       }

       //Propiedades Hibernate
       Properties asignProperties() {

           Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
           jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);

           return jpaProperties;
       }


       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource(){

          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = 
                  new DriverManagerDataSource();

          dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE");
          dataSource.setUsername("theUser");
          dataSource.setPassword("myPasswordToAskQuestions");

          return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() 
               throws ClassNotFoundException 
       {

            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = 
                    new JpaTransactionManager();

            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

            return transactionManager;
        }

}
```

and my class where i have my authenticate methods

```
package com.abc.auth;
public class AuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider 
{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo Repository_user;



    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
            throws AuthenticationException {

    UserClass user = null;
    Authentication auth = null;
    String name = null;
    String password = null;

    try 
    {
        name = authentication.getName();
        password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if( name != null  &&  
            !name.trim().equals("")  &&  
            password != null  && 
            !password.trim().equals("") )
        {
            user = this.findUserInTheDB(name); //this method returns a User

            if(user != null)
            {
                if( authUserLDAP(user .getLdapServer().getDirection(), 
                                         user .getLdapServer().getDom(), 
                                         name, password, true) ) <-- this method authenticate a user with LDAP
                {
                    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths  =  new ArrayList();
                    grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(usuario.getRole().getName()));
                    auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
                }
                else
                {
                     throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid credentials");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("the user dont exist");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid credentials");
        }
    } 
    catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("", ex.getCause());
    }

    return auth;
    }

    private UserClass findUserInTheDB(String login) 
{
    UserClass user  =  null;

    if(login  !=  null && !login.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        user  =  Repository_user.findByLogin(login);
    }

    return user  ;
}





    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
         return arg0.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    private boolean authUserLDAP(String server, String dom, String login, 
                                      String password, boolean dev) 
{
    String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    //para propositos de prueba en desarrollo
    if(dev)return true;

    try
    {
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITCTX);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + server);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, login + dominio);  

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        return false; 
    }

    return true; 
}

public void setRepositoryUser(UserRepo userRepo ) {
        this.Repository_user= userRepo ;
    }


}
```

the UserRepo Class

```
package com.abc.repo;
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository <UserClass, Long> {

    public UserClass findByLogin(String login);
}
```

this is the Console output

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 10 08:09:19 VET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.abc.config.ConfigSecurity]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configSecurity': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.abc.auth.AuthProvider com.abc.config.ConfigSecurity.authent; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.auth.AuthProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.abc.auth.AuthProvider com.abc.config.ConfigSecurity.authent; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.auth.AuthProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.auth.AuthProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Can you place the entire code for your AuthProvider? I don't see imports/annotations/package declaration. Could be nothing but still would help.

Comment: prabugp i edited the post and out the entire code

Comment: shouldn't your Authprovider be annotated with `@Component` / `@Service` to be recognized by the component-scan?

Comment: Why do you need to roll your own? Is there something that you cannot do with the default Spring Security providers? You can use the normal jdbc one for authentication and retrieve the roles from somewhere else.